# anyway to run Junit5 Parallel Tests per class at a time

Tags: java, junit5

How to run parallel test cases in junit5 using pom per test class at a time
   I have used the below configuration in my pom:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=5
```

when i am running this using clean test it launches 5 classes at a time.
    I want to run 5 threads in class at a time not 5 classes at a time

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=5
```

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1682#issuecomment-494511869

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default=same_thread
```

Comment: Note that code only answers are discouraged. Perhaps you could add some explanation regarding why you think the OP should use it - or provide a link to an explanation. By the way, have you taken the [tour]? Have you visited the [help]?

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).